# Django views query and the foreign key lookup

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm having trouble running a Django query (v1.9) within my views page. I'm basically retrieving one record from the `primers` table (that's working fine), then trying to retrieve the corresponding record from the 'gene' table:

**models.py:**

```
class Gene(models.Model):
    GeneName = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    ChromosomeNo = models.CharField(max_length=2)

class Primer(models.Model):
    PrimerName = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    Gene = models.ForeignKey(Gene)
```

**views.py**

```
def PrimerDetail(request, pk):
    primer_info = get_object_or_404(Primer, pk=pk)
    Gene_info = Gene.objects.get(Gene_id = primer_info.GeneName)
```

The problem appears to be with my use of `primer_info.GeneName`. I get:

```
'Primer' object has no attribute 'GeneName'
```

Change it to `primer_info.Gene` and I get:

> Cannot resolve keyword 'Gene_id' into field. Choices are: ChromosomeLoc, ChromosomeNo, Comments, Disease, Disease_id, GeneName, NoExons, id, primer`

I can substitute for a string value and it works fine. How should I reference a field that is a foreign key object in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's because you never have a field called `Gene_id` in your `Primer` model. Since `Gene` is the foreign key in `Primer`, it's easy to get `Gene_info`:

```
Gene_info = primer_info.Gene
```

If you want to query directly on `Gene` model(which is pretty unnecessary in your case), do:

```
Gene_info = Gene.objects.get(primer__id=primer_info.id)
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to explain it was actually the 'ChromosomeNo' field I was after, so querying the Gene model was required.But that has worked. I might have to take a few minutes to think about why, but I've very grateful!

Comment: That's the same, you could have `Gene_info = primer_info.Gene.ChromosomeNo`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

with the above description you can try out one more way of getting the Gene object this is follows as.

```
Gene_info = Gene.objects.get(pk = primer_info.Gene.id)
```

this would give you the object of Gene object that is foreign key in the Primer Table.